# How to display an Image that is stored in DB as byte[] by a <img src="?" /> in Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

I want to show an image that is stored in the databese, I have this function in my DAL that I inject to the component with the name admin:

```
 public byte[] GetCategoryLabelImage(int categoryLabelID) 
    {
        var categoryLabel = context.CategoryLabels.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Id == categoryLabelID);
        byte[] image = categoryLabel?.Image?.Image;
        return image;        
    }
```

But when I use an  tag like this:

```
<img src="@admin.GetCategoryLabelImage(label.Id)" />
```

It shows nothing, Is this the correct way to display an image?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64, @(Convert.ToBase64String(admin.GetCategoryLabelImage(label.Id)))"/>
```